# Oracle 11g - Insert Into Select / Insert and update (dbfiddle example inside)

Tags: oracle, insert, upsert

I discover few time ago and really love dbfiddle, so I made my question with example made with this wonderfull tool :-)

I've a table in my Oracle Database.

see the dbfiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2fa4b3440c660f5bba06120c07d48071

I've to add in this table thanks to this query :

> INSERT INTO STATS_CLIENT_TEST (CODECLIENT, CODEAXESTAT,
> CODEELEMENTSTAT, VALEURAXESTATISTIQUECLIENT) SELECT CODECLIENT, 174,
> 0, 1 FROM STATS_CLIENT_TEST where VALEURAXESTATISTIQUECLIENT='2021'

1000    174     0   1

1000    174     0   1

1002    174     0   1

1003    174     0   1

It's work but, I would like to get the final result here (last):

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e09d1b7c221bfc2259e36590379cbd05

1000    174     0   **2**

1002    174     0   1

1003    174     0   1

How could I have the result I try to get ?

Thank you :-)

Comment: Instead of hard-coding 1 in insert, you can do count(1).... and in end group by codeclient.

Comment: Hello Pankaj. Sorry I don't understand, do you mind if I ask you a complete example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following query in your `INSERT INTO` statement:

```
SELECT CODECLIENT, 174, 0, COUNT(*)
  FROM STATS_CLIENT_TEST
  where VALEURAXESTATISTIQUECLIENT='2021'
  GROUP BY CODECLIENT
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e5b078a37ebf731049e650f0647becc9)